# Xamarin iOS Image animation

Tags: c#, ios, image, animation, xamarin.ios

I want to animate a `UIImage`, or better said a `UIView`. I've got a `Background` consisting of multiple layers where each layer should be animated a little differently (lets assume this is a picture of a jungle and the second background layer is a plant). My first thoughts were to use a gif, but sadly this results in poor quality and big image sizes. The next thought was to use a "sprite sheet" image where the animation consists of 4 images which will be updated every 0.x seconds. Well this could work but i wanted to code as much as possible and use as less images as possible.

After the background is animated I want to animate a monkey running from the left to the right side. For sure the monkey itself should a animated and it should do this again after a random amount of seconds.

Which way would you implement such a thing and where would you start?

## Edit

Forgot to mention that this should run with as low battery usage as possible

Comment: I would suggest you look into SpriteKit which will fulfil your needs quick and easy to use

Comment: This seems a good starting point, will check this out soon

Comment: You can do all you said in SpriteKit Scene Editor without a line of code as well

Comment: Okay so I implemented it now with SpriteKit. This was super easy and the result looks awesome. Thanks for your help!